# How to query Many-To-Many SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

[image]

Import `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy` modules first:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Declare the `app` and `db` objects:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///inquestion.db' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

There are three tables: `Artist`, `Album` and `Genre`. The `Artist` object can be linked to multiple `Albums`. And the `Album` object can be linked to multiple `Artists`. The `albums_to_artists_table` is to keep the relationship between the `Artists` and `Albums` tight:

```
albums_to_artists_table = db.Table('albums_to_artists_table',
                          db.Column('album_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('album.id')),
                          db.Column('artist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artist.id')))

class Genre(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)


class Album(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    genre_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('genre.id'))

    artists = db.relationship('Artist', backref='albums', lazy='dynamic', secondary=albums_to_artists_table)

class Artist(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    _albums = db.relationship('Album', secondary=albums_to_artists_table, backref=db.backref('albums_to_artists_table_backref', lazy='dynamic'))
```

So we have the `Artist` linked to the `Album` which is linked to `Genre` and it looks like this: `Artist` > `Album` > `Genre`.

Having this setup in place we go ahead and create the `Genre` object first:

```
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

genre = Genre(name='Heavy Metal')
db.session.add(genre)
db.session.commit()
```

Then two albums:

```
album1 = Album(name='Ride the Lightning', genre_id = genre.id)
album2 = Album(name='Master of Puppets ', genre_id = genre.id)
db.session.add(album1)
db.session.add(album2)
db.session.commit()
```

And the artist:

```
artist = Artist(name='Metallica',  _albums=[album1, album2])

db.session.add(artist)
db.session.commit()
```

After the database created we can query what `Albums` are linked to `Genre`:

```
print Album.query.filter_by(genre_id=1).all()
```

and what `Artists` are linked to `Album`:

```
print Artist.query.filter(Artist._albums.any(id=album1.id)).all()
```

Now I would like to query all the `Artists` that are linked to a `Genre` passing the genre.id. How to achieve it?

Comment: hmmm, your relationship doesn't seem right to me....with your current relationship one album can only have one genre, which means that for an Artist to be linked to x genre's he has to have x number of albums also....is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes, It is intentional that the Album and Genre have one to one relationship.

Comment: Given the example above how do I query artists which have more than 1 album ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can apply a filter in `Artist.albums.any()`, which will generate a subquery:

```
Artist.query.filter(Artist.albums.any(genre_id=genre.id)).all()
```

Or you can use a `join()` on albums:

```
Artist.query.join(Artist.albums).filter_by(genre_id=genre.id).all()
```